# How can I protect against or remove Doom once it's cast?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I am a Dragoon in Final Fantasy 14, and completed all job quests already. While fighting in a level 40 dungeon a while ago (I don't remember which and don't think it's relevant), the first or second boss (not the final boss) cast Doom on me. After a short while, my character instantly died. This was very frustrating, and somehow this didn't affect/kill the other party members. As it was a random party, I couldn't really ask them how they were protected or removed the status.

All my search attempts on Google gave unclear results, at best.

So, how can I be protected against Doom, or how can I remove it once it was already cast on me?

Comment: Completely unrelated to this question, but since you're in a Level 40 dungeon, I assume your Lancer is above level 30. At level 30 you can start a special quest at your class guild as part of your class questline that unlocks the Dragoon job, a straight upgrade for your class. At your level you're balanced around already having it, so I recommend you catch up on those quests ASAP, because you're holding back your groups if you don't.

Comment: @Nzall yeah it was already asked and deleted (by mods), I've completed all Dragoon quests up to level 50 (I'm level 51 now). I'm fine in attacks and can heal fairly well (Bloodbath, Second Wind, potions) but things like Doom or attacking a boss with healer that doesn't heal me on time still cause me to die sometimes.

Comment: @Nzall should I edit and write that I'm a Dragoon instead of Lancer?

Comment: That's probably a good idea, even if only to eliminate confusion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is most likely the first boss in the Sunken Temple of Qarn, which periodically inflicts Doom on the entire party. This specific Doom effect can only be removed by stepping on one of three large tiles on the floor, marked by a glowing red effect.

Other types of Doom effects exist, usually the debuff's tooltip will tell you how it can be removed.

> As it was random party, couldn't really ask them how they were protected or removed the status.

Of course you can ask! Most players I've met in the Duty Finder have been nothing but helpful towards newbies.

Answer (score 14):

There are a total of 4 different types of Doom in FFXIV:

- Sometimes you need to step on a glowing floor tile

  - Examples: Sunken Temple of Qarn first boss, World of Darkness first boss
- Sometimes it needs to be Esuna'd off by a healer

  - Example: First boss of Dun Scaith
- Sometimes the target needs to be healed to full health

  - Example: Seat of Sacrifice
- Sometimes it's a punishment for messing up a major mechanic in a Savage raid with no way to remove it

  - I've seen this show up in one of the Eden Savage raids, although I don't recall which one

Comment: In the last instance, this type of Doom can also happen outside of Savage raids -- for example, Delubrum Reginae also causes the _Thrice-come Ruin_ debuff, where stacking it three times results in Doom. In this raid tier, e10s has _Thrice-come Ruin_, and e12s has _Twice-come Ruin_.

Comment: Worth noting that the effect applied in the Seat of Sacrifice is 'True Walking Dead', not 'Doom' - though full healing removes it nonetheless.

Comment: Indeed, a better example of the third type would be the third boss of Orbonne Monastery.

Answer (score 0):

[Doom (status) on the Final Fantasy Wiki - Final Fantasy XIV section:](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Doom_(status)#Final_Fantasy_XIV)

Emphasis mine:

> Doom is a status that knocks out the victim within a certain amount of time receiving it. The amount of time before it triggers depends on the user. Some variants of Doom can be removed by **Esuna**, some require the victim to **be healed to full HP to remove**, and **some can't be removed at all**.

---

There seem to be at least three different [types](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XIV_statuses#Doom) of Doom, with some tooltips when hovered over, or however the Wiki gets the information. The icon with a blue dot appears to be the kind that goes away at full health.

---

[Esuna in FFXIV:](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Esuna_(ability)#Final_Fantasy_XIV)

> Esuna is a cross-role ability available at level 20 for all healer role classes and jobs. The spell removes a single detrimental status effect from the selected target.

Comment: Thanks, I've read it already as part of "All my search attempts on Google gave unclear results" which I mentioned. The "some" and "variants" is what I don't get. Doom is pretty simple: status effect causing death in fixed amount of time. What are its "variants"? Also, I've never seen Esuna in FF14, and I'm already level 50, so if it's a thing, it's way too rare/hard to get to be relevant. Again, not your fault and thanks for the answer, if you can explain things it would be awesome. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 - Esuna has its own page on the Wiki... I don't think you can heal it, as a Lancer, since it seems like a Healer only thing, as per the info I just added?